# SQL Server stored procedure using a temp table field as the where clause for a select

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a single column temp table `#colors` in a stored procedure. The column is called `color`. I want to query another table `tblMain` with a `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT userid
FROM tblMain
WHERE color = 'red' OR color = 'white' or color = 'blue'
```

but I don't want the `WHERE` clause to be static (as in the example above), I want it to use the color field from the `#colors` table to form the `WHERE` clause.

Is this even possible ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can use like this

SELECT userid FROM tblMain 
WHERE color IN (SELECT distinct color FROM #colors)
```

Comment: The DISTINCT is probably important ? Would the INNER JOIN way GolezTrol mentioned do the same thing ? If tblMain had millions of records which would be the preferred way of doing this: INNER JOIN or SELECT in and IN clause? Thank you and thank GolezTrol for your help.

Comment: you can the below url    it will useful   http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/

Answer (score 3):

You can use a select in an `in` clause:

```
SELECT userid FROM tblMain 
WHERE color IN (SELECT color FROM colors)
```

or just an (inner) join:

```
SELECT userid FROM tblMain 
INNER JOIN colors ON colors.color = tblMain.color
```